# learn more; read more

Tags: vocabulary

> 1. Nancy, we're still trying to learn **more** about the situation.
> 2. You can read **more** about all of this on my blog.
>      (All are from COCA)

In both the case above, is ‘*more*’ an adverb or pronoun? When I interpret it in my own tongue, it’s very likely to be adverbial, but I have no idea what it would be like in your own tongue.

Comment: Dictionary definitions of [more](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/more) do not list any pronoun usages. Can you elaborate why you think "more" in your examples might be a pronoun?

Comment: "More" describes a quantity here. How much did she read? More (than she had previously read).

Comment: @user3169 you can see [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adverbs.htm

"More" is an adverb of degree.

Adverbs of Degree

```
That is the farthest I have ever jumped.
(farthest - adverb of degree)

He boxed more cleverly.
(more cleverly - adverb of degree and manner.)
```

It often helps to pose the question where the adverb is the answer.  Does the adverb make sense as the answer?

Nancy, we're still trying to learn about the situation.
Nancy asks: How much are they trying to learn about the situation?  More.

Comment: I've often wanted websites to add a 'learn less' link, so I could forget the useless information they give out after I've found the part I wanted.

Comment: That comes automatically with age.  If you still remember things, just "wait for it."